# Indoor Map Navigation for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am trying to build an app that has indoor navigation with routes. Do flutter have packages for this? See sample picture below from dentreality.com

[image]

As you can see there is a route that guides the user on what isle is the selected item.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, have you found anything?

Comment: @Eyjafl got nothing unfortunately man.

Comment: @Riki have you found any solution yet?